# How to search series of number to be found directly in the shop statement so i can key in the values according to the series that I want?

Tags: excel, database, sorting, filtering

With two different spreadsheets, I need to key in shop deduction in the payslip together with the shop statement. It takes longer time to key in one by one when using only Search between the payslip and the shop statement. It would be better if i can get a series of number to be found in the statement.

1.Payroll for Factory 1 (213 workers divided unequally into 15 groups )

(Name-Shop deduction)

(1st group)

K-$1.00
C-$1.55
Z-$0.95
M-$2.32
R-$3.05
A1-$6.99
T-$50.00

2.Statement that should be to key in one by one according to the payroll containing Factory 1 combined with Factory 2, Factory 3, Factory 4.

(Name-Shop deduction)

A-$5.99
B-$0.77
C-$1.55
D-$4.40
E-None
F-$30.97
G-$8.99
H-$23.90
I-$7.00
J-$8.99
K-$1.00
L-$47.99
M-$2.32
.
.
R-$3.05
.
.
Z-$0.95
A1-$6.99
B1-$34.50

(......list continue up to 1000)

1.How to sort the statement  according to the 1st group sequence so I can key in faster? Using SEARCH one by one between the payroll and the shop statement, then key in one by one into the statement after that taking so much time.

Comment: Can you show an example of what you are looking to do? A screen shot, or a step by step process, which can be turned into code, or a formula

Comment: I already simplified the process. I can't adding image because not qualified to do that. I hope you can understand what I mean.

Comment: Sounds like you could use auto-filter on the columns.  Select just one Shop deduction code and key the similar deductions.  If you also select un-keyed deduction then each new Shop deduction code selected will make your list to enter shorter